# How to create a .pwd file for signing APK Set for Bundle Tool?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

So I was trying [Bundle Tool](https://github.com/google/bundletool) to test App Bundle. Now I learned that you can't install the generated apks to a device if you don't sign it.

According to [Android Documentation of Bundle Tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool), there are two ways to provide the signing key passwords:

1) You could use a file .pwd, such as `pass=file:/path/to/file` or,
2) Use the password themselves with "pass:", such as `pass=pass:password`

My question are:
1) How do you generate a .pwd to use for the Bundle Tool?
2) Is there any advantage of use the .pwd file?
3) Is there any good practice around this or should I not care at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password file is just a text file with the password in plain text. This is useful for CI or other programs to avoid having the password hardcoded and visible in the command line, and when the file's access can be restricted.

A third way of entering the password is by not providing it at all on the command line, in which case bundletool will prompt for it when it needs it. This would be the recommended way if you run the command manually so the password is never stored on disk.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! :D